# How to implement a process manager in event sourcing

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm working on a small example application to learn the concepts of CQRS and event sourcing. I have a `Basket` aggregate and a `Product` aggregate which should work independently.

Here's some pseudo code to show the implementation

```
Basket { BasketId; OrderLines; Address; }

// basket events
BasketCreated { BasketId; }
ItemAdded { BasketId; ProductId; Quantity }
AddItemSucceeded { BasketId; ProductId; Quantity }
AddItemRevoked { BasketId; ProductId; Quantity }
ItemRemoved { BasketId; ProductId; Quantity }
CheckedOut { BasketId; Address }

Product { ProductId; Name; Price; }

// product events
ProductReserved { ProductId; Quantity }
ProductReservationFailed { ProductId; Quantity }
ProductReservationCancelled { ProductId; Quantity; }
```

Commands are pretty similar to the events, using the imperative name and not past tense.

Right now these work just fine independently. I issue a command `AddItem`, and it creates a `ItemAdded` event on the `Basket` aggregate which does what it needs to do with the state of the 'Basket'. Similarly, for product the command and events work just fine.

I'd now like to combine this into a process which would go something like this (in terms of commands and events that happen):

The process manager would do the following:

```
on BasketCreated: CreateShoppingProcess
on ItemAdded: ReserveProduct
on ProductReserved: SucceedAddingItem // does nothing, but needs to be there so that the basket knows it can check out
on ProductReservationFailed: RevokeAddItem
on RemoveItem: CancelProductReservation
on Checkout: CreateOrder // create an order and so on...
```

The questions that I couldn't find definitive answers to are:

1. Do I need to persist the process manager? It seems like I do, but I'm not sure
2. If I do, I need to save the events for the process manager. However, the events that It's listening to are tied to the aggregates. Do I add the process id to those? Do I have separate events just for the process manager? How to do this and keep as DRY as possible
3. How do I know what basket the `ProductReserved` events are for? Is it OK to have a `BasketId` on those too, or is that leaking info?
4. How do I keep a relationship between events, how do I know which `ItemAdded` produced which `ProductReserved` event? Do I pass along an `EventId`? This seems odd...
5. Should I implement the `Basket` as a process manager instead of a simple aggregate?

After some more research I came to this:
A Saga is something that keeps its own events and listens to events from the outside. Basically, it's an Aggregate that can also react to events happening outside it's own little world.

A Process Manager works with the events from the outside and sends out commands. It's history can be rebuilt from the events that have happened on the Aggregates which share a common identifier like a correlationId.

Comment: It seems you're trying to encode in your system a formal process that paraphrases an existing informal use case made of a series of commands. Doing that, it looks like you're creating a number of redundant commands and events besides the existing ones. Is that your intention? What is the business need behind formalizing things as a process in code? What in your domain requires you to identify this process and reason about it as a full fledged concept?

Comment: This is a totally made up project where the purpose is to learn how to make two relatively independent aggregates work together. So there's really no real "business need", And I am trying to avoid redundancy in these commands and events as much as possible. Hence the confusion with the process manager., because it seems that is should not repeat stuff that the aggregates are already handling. However, I need to keep a connection between these two aggregates somehow. It seems that using causation and correlation might help, but I need to try it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Review what Rinat Abdullin wrote about [evolving business process](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/).  In particular, notice his recommendation for developing a business process in a fast changing environment -- a process manager is "just" an automated replacement for a human being staring at a screen.

My own mental model of a process manager is that it is an event sourced projection that you can query for a list of pending commands.

> Do I need to persist the process manager? It seems like I do, but I'm not sure

It's a read model.  You can rebuild the process manager from the history of events each time you need it; or you can treat it like a snapshot that you update.

> If I do, I need to save the events for the process manager.

No - the process manager is a *manager*.  It doesn't do anything useful on its own; instead it tells aggregates to do work (ie, make changes to the book of record).

> How do I know what basket the ProductReserved events are for? Is it OK to have a BasketId on those too, or is that leaking info

Sure.  *Note:* in most "real" shopping domains, you wouldn't insist on reserving inventory before processing an order; it adds unnecessary contention to the business.  It's more likely that your business would want to accept the order, then apologize in the rare case that the order can't be fulfilled in the required time.

> How do I keep a relationship between events, how do I know which ItemAdded produced which ProductReserved event?

Messages have meta data - in particular, you can include a causationIdentifier (so you can identify which commands produced which events) and a [correlationIdentifier](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CorrelationIdentifier.html), to generally track the conversation.

For instance, the process manager writes its own id as the correlationId in the command; the events produced by a copy the correlation id of the command, and your process manager subscribes to all events that have its own correlationId.

> Should I implement the Basket as a process manager instead of a simple aggregate?

My recommendation is no.  *But* Udi Dahan has a different opinion that you should review; which is that [CQRS only makes sense if your aggregates are sagas](http://udidahan.com/2011/04/22/when-to-avoid-cqrs/) -- Udi used saga in the place where process manager has become the dominant spelling.

> should process managers retrieve aggregates?

Not really?  Process managers are primarily concerned with orchestration, not domain state.  An instance of a process will have "state", in the form of a history of all of the events that they have observed -- the correct thing to do in response to event Z depends on whether or not we have seen events X and Y.  So you may need to be able to store and load a representation of that state (which could be something flat, or could be the history of observed events).

(I say "not really" because *aggregate* is defined vaguely enough that it's not completely wrong to claim that list of observed events *is* an "aggregate".  The differences are more semantic than implementation -- we load *process state* and then decide what messages to send to the parts of the system responsible for *domain state*.  There's a bit of hand waving going on here.)

> So the PM does not need to use one type of state management over another because it is only responsible for doing stuff live and never during replays?

Not quite - state management isn't a do-er, it's a keeper tracker of-er.  In circumstances where the process manger shouldn't emit any signals, you give it inert connections to the world.  In other words, `dispatch(command)` is a no-op.

Comment: You say:  You can rebuild the process manager from the history of events each time you need it...
But to rebuild it, I need to save events for it. Or should I be rebuilding it from the events in the aggregates? The part I'm struggling with is: with aggregates, the events have the aggregate id, and it's easy to rebuild by finding all the events with that aggregate id. But how would I do that for the process manager? Should I be doing that for the process manager? Or should the process manager be looking up the aggregates when it needs to decide something based on an event that came in?

Comment: What I was missing was the notion of causation and correlation in event sourcing. Once I looked into that, then your answer to the fourth question finally made sense.

Comment: I would love an answer to @IvanPintar 's first comment; should process managers retrieve aggregates? Should they build their own based on the events it processes? In that case it's event handlers would need to be side-effect free, right?

Comment: @Jeff In one example that I did the process manager had it's own storage which was updated with each processed event, a kind of a read model. This was simple to do and it was easy to track what it already processed.
In another example, the process manager created and stored it's own events, built off of the aggregate events. Similar to above, but the state was event-sourced.
Depending on the complexity of the state that the process manager keeps, it might be easier to do one or the other. I found the first approach simpler.

Comment: Interesting, so it's more or less up to the developer as long as the process manager responds to events and dispatches commands in the end?

Comment: @Jeff let me know if my latest edit clarifies anything.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! So the PM does not need to use one type of state management over another because it is only responsible fof doing stuff live and never during replays?

Comment: This is very interesting. But could you elaborate on your last comment? How do you ensure a command handler does not dispatch commands during replays? If the command is ti send an email I wouldn't want the PM to send an email again if for whatever reason is replaying all the events from position 0. How do you guarantee idempotency there? Any good read about this? Thanks @voiceofunreason

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for has a pattern called a "Saga", which is essentially a process manager.

Saga's are perfect for long running processes too, because it can maintain state between correlated commands.

[Here is a great article on Sagas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx)